# Error method sendAll() in nodejs using firebase-admin

Tags: node.js, firebase-admin

I use firebase-admin for nodejs(version 7.3.0) for sending push 
notifications. For 40k distinct messages sending with method sendAll often server received this error:

"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" 
property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the 
following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: 
socket hang up. Error code: ECONNRESET".

Sometimes it works well but not all the time.

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
serviceAccount = require('/path_json_adminsdk/yyyyyyyyyy.json');

var defaultApp = admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://api-project-yyyyyy'
});

var k = 42000;
var contorMessages = 0;
var messages = [];
for(var i=0;i <em><</em> k; i++){
    //.......
    contorMessages = contorMessages + 1;
    var tmp = {
        alert: body.alert,
        payload: body.payload
    };

    //form the array to be sent
        messages.push({
            data: {"body": JSON.stringify(tmp)},
        token: body.token
    });

    if(contorMessages == 100){       
        SEDispatcher.emit('sendMessageFirebaseMulticast',messages);
        contorMessages = 0;
        messages = [];
    }

}

SEDispatcher.on('sendMessageFirebaseMulticast', function(messages){
    var dryRun = true;

    admin.messaging().sendAll(messages, dryRun)
    .then(function(response) {
        //console.log("response:",response);
        //responses = response.responses;
        //.......
     })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(' +++ Error sending message:', error);
    });

});
```

the error that occurs sometimes:

> +++ Error sending message: { Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a
>   valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error
>   fetching access token: Error while making request: socket hang up.
>   Error code: ECONNRESET".
>       at FirebaseAppError.Error (native)
>       at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/opt/node/test/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
>       at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/opt/node/test/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
>       at new FirebaseAppError (/opt/node/test/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:122:28)
>       at /opt/node/test/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-app.js:121:23
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)   errorInfo:    { code: 'app/invalid-credential',
>        message: 'Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2
>   access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token:
>   Error while making request: socket hang up. Error code: ECONNRESET".'
>   },   codePrefix: 'app' }

Answer (score 0):

```
const messaging = getMessaging(defaultApp);
```

Need to be load

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
let serviceAccount = require('./google.json');

function messaging() {
  const defaultApp = initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
  });
  const messaging = getMessaging(defaultApp);
  const topic = 'highScores';
  const message = [
    {
      data: {
        score: '850',
        time: '2:45'
      },
      topic: topic
    }
  ];
  messaging
    .sendAll(message, true)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log('response:', response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(' +++ Error sending message:', error);
    });
}
```

Assuming that the JSON is the file that contains your private key that is generated when registering the project